# Looking to covert list of PMID and DOIs to Bibliometric Excel files

Tags: excel, mendeley

So I'm not sure if I'm posting this to the right group, but hopefully someone can point me into the right direction.

Basically, I have a list of many PMID and DOI numbers for online journals. I'd like to be able to import these into Mendeley, and create an output of tab-delimited excel files with each heading (author name, issue, year, etc) separated into different columns. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the API for this task. With your list of DOIs or PMIDs, you can use the [query the catalog](http://dev.mendeley.com/methods/#retrieving-catalog-documents) and get back all the bibliographic data. The data will be returned as a JSON object that looks like this:

```
    [
  {
    "title": "Bayesian network meta-analysis to evaluate interferon-free treatments in naive patients with genotype 1 hepatitis C virus infection",
    "type": "journal",
    "authors": [
      {
        "first_name": "Sabrina",
        "last_name": "Trippoli"
      },
      {
        "first_name": "Valeria",
        "last_name": "Fadda"
      },
      {
        "first_name": "Dario",
        "last_name": "Maratea"
      },
      {
        "first_name": "Andrea",
        "last_name": "Messori"
      }
    ],
    "year": 2015,
    "source": "European Journal of Gastroenterology & Hepatology",
    "identifiers": {
      "doi": "10.1097/MEG.0000000000000389",
      "issn": "0954-691X"
    },
    "id": "f7d2d642-fe21-3a0c-b1fb-a5db3ec55b41",
    "link": "http://www.mendeley.com/research/bayesian-network-metaanalysis-evaluate-interferonfree-treatments-naive-patients-genotype-1-hepatitis"
  }
]
```

If you want it in a form amenable to manipulation in a spreadsheet, you'll need to convert the structured JSON into a flatfile format. Here's an example using R to [create a dataframe from a DOI input](https://github.com/Mendeley/mendeley-api-r-example/blob/master/mendeley.R). The dataframe can then be written out as a tab-delimited file using [`write.delim`](http://www.inside-r.org/node/54936).

Of course, once you have an R dataframe, you may find it easier to do your analysis within R, as there are [packages for doing bibliometric analysis](https://r-forge.r-project.org/softwaremap/tag_cloud.php?tag=bibliometrics) available.

You may have hoping to use the desktop client to avoid having to write any code, but R is pretty easy to pick up and all the tricky parts of the code are already written for you, so I hope this gets you started.